# c# windows forms stop execution until button_Click (without an infinite loop)

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I am trying to write a windows forms application that stop until button click (without an infinite loop that check a flag or something like that)
right now i am using a second Thread that execute the program and stops until event

current code:

```
static void Main(){
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(Start).Start();
    }
```

Start() is where all my code is, i stop the execution by:

```
static AutoResetEvent handle = new AutoResetEvent(false); 
    public void Start()
    {
        Massage("Hello World", "Continue");
        //stop now
        handle.WaitOne();
        //after button_click
        Massage("user pushed the button", "Continue");
    }
private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        handle.Set();
    }
```

the problem with this is every time i change something in the form in need to use a delegate , example:

```
    public void Massage(string massage, string button){
        if (this.Action.InvokeRequired)
        {
            StringArgReturningVoidDelegate d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(Massage);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { massage, button });
        }
        else
        {
            this.Action.Text = massage;
            this.NextButton.Text = button;
        }
    }
```

I tried to do the same thing without the second thread but than when the execution stops all the form is freezes (and i can't push the button).

The question is if there is any way to stop the program until button_click and still let you access the form objects without the use of

```
if (this.Action.InvokeRequired)
        {
            StringArgReturningVoidDelegate d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(Massage);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { massage, button });
        }
```

any time you want to change something in the form?

sorry for the poor English and thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Not sure if I understand entirely but-- Forms don't execute without pressing a button or having something in the same block as `InitializeComponent();` . Your `Massage()` method also seems to be that of `MessageBox`, which is already a C# class. From what I can tell (which may not be a lot) , I don't see an infinite loop. You could show the messages like `MessageBox.Show("Hello, world!", "Continue", MessageBox.Buttons.OK)` . (I don't know for sure enough to post an answer quite yet)

Comment: The code you posted _(after a fix - missing function)_ works, but is not stable. I got an exception on first run. This was caused by running thread from constructor _(the form was not yet fully initialised)_. Move the `new Thread(Start).Start();` to `Form1_Load` function and check form properties. Mostly the property `Enabled`. And you can simplify the invoke: `this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Massage(massage, button); });`

Comment: Symon - I didn't understand you ,  first of all the start function is an example and not the function in my program (there is more to the code than what i showed here), the code , as of right now, is working perfectly i am just searching for a option to change things in the form without the need for all the this.Action.InvokeRequired code.

Comment: Julo - the code is not the problem (as i said before this is now the full code , and the full code is working), the problem is with the delegate invoke that i need to do every time that i want to change something in the form.
thank you for the simplified way , but there is a way to fix the delegate invoke problem and just change the form as you would do if you have only one thread?

Comment: Please specify your question more detailed _(edit the question, not in comments)_. C# has limitation and only GUI thread can access to GUI elements. The `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` is the only way how to change values from another thread. Second option is using `BackgroundWorker`, that already executes these request on GUI thread _(when started from GUI thread)_ and you do not need to use invoke. There is simply no other way as using invoke directly, or indirectly.

Comment: thank you , i edited the question , if this is not understandable please tell me .
any way i like more information about the  BackgroundWorker option?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503254/2826535) - this is not a answer to your question, but another using `BackgroundWorker`. The way you stop the second thread is a correct way, or at least partially. You still need to handle events like "cancel" and closing the application.