# Display different numbers in a textBox

Tags: c#, loops, textbox

I want to write a code that displays numbers `1` to `10` in a `textBox`. Following code has been written by me. But unfortunately only number `10` is displayed in `textBox`. What is wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int i,j;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
            for (j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the last value 'i' has in the for loop every time you iterate. Therefore, 10 is displayed as that is the last number to iterate. Possibly look at using a string builder.

Comment: When you have this in a single function on GUI thread you can not see this. The value changes, but unfortunately your code block the GUI thread and the value will not be displayed until the function 'Click' ends. And the when the function ends, the value is already 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
```

Overwrites the textbox text each loop.  You want:

```
textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString(i) + " ";
```

Note, there are others ways of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Set default value of text box to 0 and then just increment it on button click

```
 private void button1_Click(object           
    sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.Int32(textBox1.Text)+1);
    for (j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) ;
    {

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do work in GUI thread. When you have some simple work (small calculation), then there is not a problem. But when you have a loner work, move the work to background worker.

This is the correct way how to do this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BackgroundWorkerExample
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private BackgroundWorker worker;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
      this.worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
      this.worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
      this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
      this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) => this.button1.Enabled = true;

    private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.textBox1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

    private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
      {
        this.worker.ReportProgress(i);

        // do work
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.button1.Enabled = false;
      this.worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

The button *(after the operation starts)* is disabled to be inactive. The reason is, to prevent try second execution of the background thread. When the background worker ends, the button is enabled.

Comment: @Greg: Yes, a little bit complex, but when you need to display something while processing data, this is the correct way. The second possible way _(executing work in GUI thread)_ is not a good way of doing this.

Comment: IMHO, this is more than a "little bit complex" for a new developer, even if it is the right way to do it.  When I was still learning at a basic level, this would have confused me more than show me why I had this issue.

Comment: I hope it is not that complex, that it will be too confusing. Unfortunately i have seen _(or better to say, it was e-mail tech support)_ 'experienced' programmers, that have run a few seconds _(with maximal time up to 70 seconds)_ tasks in GUI thread after pressing button. And I say, that they were not cheap programs with this 'feature' of freezing GUI thread, unfortunately. Therefore it is better to teach the right way how to do thinks from the start.